# jQuery Popup Window Return Value to Parent in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

How can I accomplish the following using jQuery: Open a popup window that returns a value to the parent window when a link in the child window is clicked, close the child window, and then have the parent automatically fill a form based on the value returned?

Answer (score 1):

You may try using a jquery popup plugin, that loads inside the window itself. Here are some examples http://djdesignerlab.com/2012/06/08/10-useful-jquery-popup-plugins/ and you may google for more. Then on popup window close, catch the text into a variable and pass that variable to parent form, and using .html() function, you can change (or update) the text.

Comment: i have grid in my popup, how should i select mutlipe vlaues in that.. thanks for your efforts..